# displaying JSON data in flatlist

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to display Json Data in a Flatlis component in my react-native App, but i can't figure out how to display it. I want to show the name of the dinosaur in a List and if i press on the list item i want to show the dimensions of the dinosaur.
I have the List items and the Detail screen all set up, but i get a blank screen with this code, did I import the JSON data in a wrong way or do i somehow have to restructure the data to display it?

I have JSON data like this:

```
{
    "lambeosaurus": {
        "dimensions": {
            "height": 2.1,
            "length": 12.5,
            "weight": 5000
        }
    },
    "stegosaurus": {
        "dimensions": {
            "height": 4,
            "length": 9,
            "weight": 2500
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native'

import MyListItem from '../components/MyListItem'

const data = require("../data/MockData.json")

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <StatusBar hidden={true} />
                <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={({ item }) =>
                        <MyListItem
                            item={item}
                            onPress={() => {
                                this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
                                    item: item
                                })
                            }}
                        />
                    }
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}



export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FlatList` expects an array as `data` prop, but your JSON is an object. You could change it into an array before using it.

```js
// const objData = require("../data/MockData.json");
const objData = {
  lambeosaurus: {
    dimensions: {
      height: 2.1,
      length: 12.5,
      weight: 5000
    }
  },
  stegosaurus: {
    dimensions: {
      height: 4,
      length: 9,
      weight: 2500
    }
  }
};

const data = Object.keys(objData).map(key => ({
  key,
  ...objData[key]
}));

console.log(data);
```